# Cordova webview cannot load Google Maps api keys for IOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-maps, security

I have written a Cordova app that uses Google Maps.  It is currently available in both appstores.  Google recently started to warn users about using Google Maps without an API Key...

`"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"`

This implies they will soon enforce the use of API Keys.  I followed the instructions in the Google Developer Console to create an API Key for each platform my app supports...

- Desktop/Mobile browsers (browser api key with *.mydomain.com for
  referrer)
- IOS (IOS api key with specific bundle ID)
- Android (Android api key with package name and sha-1 fingerprint)

The Browser API Key works fine for desktop browsers when the app is deployed from my domain.  However, the IOS or Android API Keys do NOT work when my app is packaged as a Cordova app and run on phones.  I get an invalid api key message in the console and my app does not load.

If I use the Browser API Key everywhere, it works as long as the referrer list is empty, which is required for Cordova apps which load from a local file: URL.  But this is not a solution.  Anyone who got the API Key could use it freely and I would incur their usage on my account.  I want to use the IOS/Android API Keys as they provide options to lockdown the usage of the API Key to just my app.

QUESTION: Is there a way to convince Google that my Maps instance running in a Cordova webview is really running on Android or IOS and accept my respective API Keys?

There are Cordova plugins for Google Maps that accept IOS/Android keys and it apparently works.  However, I'm loading Google Maps directly and would rather not have to use a plugin in the middle.  I think the problem is that Google Maps thinks it's running in a browser, when it's really running inside a Cordova app on Android or IOS.  Surely there must be a way to make this work, perhaps using config.xml or AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I believe the JS, Android, and IOS SDKs are all different SDKs.  What I'm trying to do is use the JS SDK with the native IOS/Android API Keys for better lockdown.  This does not appear to be possible at the moment.

Comment: Hi @jmelvin, did you manage to sort this out? I am using the API simply for route directions and also don't want to have to include a whole plugin to display maps when I wont ever be showing the user a map.

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution yet. There API Key will be required at some point and there is no apparent interim solution to capture errors with keys.  Note: to use the Google Maps related APIs, you might have to display a map of some sort, per the license agreement.  You might recheck this.